# How do i append an external reactjs component onClick using hooks

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

i'm completely new to reactjs. How do i append an external jsx with an onClick function(Just once) using react hooks?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array variable in your main jsx(App.js) state like shown below

```
    state = {
        externaljsx: []
    }
```

For button onClick event call function addExternal to add external JSX

```
    addExternal = () => {
        this.setState({
             externaljsx: [this.state.externaljsx, <NameofyourJSX />]
        })
    }
```

Please note  should be your JSX component name.